# how configure chrony in orphan mode

Tags: linux, centos7, ntp, chrony

I have two centos servers without internet i tried to enable orphan mode so they synch with each other but still time is not synchronized between them.

Find below my settings and output of commands

**/etc/chrony.conf**

```
#server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
#server 3.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst

driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 1.0 3
rtcsync
local stratum 10 orphan
logdir /var/log/chrony
allow 192.168.0.0/20
```

**timedatectl**

```
    Local time: Fri 2019-10-11 16:28:06 CEST
  Universal time: Fri 2019-10-11 14:28:06 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-10-11 14:28:06
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: yes
 Last DST change: DST began at
                  Sun 2019-03-31 01:59:59 CET
                  Sun 2019-03-31 03:00:00 CEST
 Next DST change: DST ends (the clock jumps one hour backwards) at
                  Sun 2019-10-27 02:59:59 CEST
                  Sun 2019-10-27 02:00:00 CET
```

**chronyc sources**

```
210 Number of sources = 0
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
```

**chronyc tracking**

```
Reference ID    : 7F7F0101 ()
Stratum         : 10
Ref time (UTC)  : Fri Oct 11 14:28:35 2019
System time     : 0.000000000 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 0.000 ppm slow
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 0.000000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.000000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration isn't correct, because this isn't how orphan mode is designed to work.  Orphan mode is designed to provide a set of configured peers with adequate time sync for a limited time when lower-stratum servers become unreachable.  It isn't designed to support full offline operation (NTP doesn't work like that).

Your servers aren't syncing with each other because your configuration doesn't include them as peers with each other, and neither one is synced with lower stratum servers.

Read more about orphan mode:

- http://doc.ntp.org/current-stable/orphan.html
- https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/3.5/chrony.conf.html#local